# I cannot install any node package with npm

Tags: networking, npm, dns

I upgraded my npm to the latest version and now I can't run any npm command again, I uninstalled the node js and downloaded it again, 
when I ran `npm install -g ionic@latest` I got this error in my command prompt:

```
npm WARN deprecated ionic@5.4.16: The Ionic CLI now uses ✨ @ionic/cli ✨ for its package name!  https://twitter.com/ionicframework/status/1223268498362851330
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/env-paths failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\De Stone Of David\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-23T11_48_48_277Z-debug.log
```

I don't know what to do now, I also ran `npm cache clean --force` in powershell as admin and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where reading the error message carefully can help. The key line is

> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/env-paths failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org

ENOTFOUND is a message delivered by your OS to npm. It means npm's attempt to use the Domain Name Service (DNS) to look up that registry machine's hostname failed.

So, you have a networking-connectivity problem, or, less likely, a firewall problem. Try this on a command line on your machine.

```
curl https://registry.npmjs.org
```

If it, too, doesn't work, try rebooting your machine. If that doesn't work, ask a network engineer for help and mention the curl command as evidence of the problem.

Some home ISPs (I'm looking at you, Comcast) sometimes have connectivity trouble that shows up as DNS failures. Power-cycle your cable modem and router. If that doesn't help, call tech support and ask them to reset your modem remotely.

If you have a VPN in use try disconnecting from it, then try your npm operation again. If it works without the VPN, then ask the person who maintains the VPN for help.

I have no trouble getting to that hostname from my location.

Comment: My network is working very well, I am not behind a firewall and not using vpn